# Using CSS3 to give per three table rows a background color

Tags: html, css, html-table

An odd question maybe, but I want to use `CSS3` to do this, but I am not sure if it's possible. I tried to experiment with `nth-child` and `nth-of-type`, but I could not get it to work. I guess it's very hard to get what I want without using Javascript.

Anyhow, let me tell you what I want...

I have three `<tr>` elements in a `table` which I want to give a background color. Beneath these table rows, we have three more table rows. Those will not get a different color. The problem: how do you select them? With `even` or `odd`, it's not possible... but *is there a possibility to combine nth-of-type with even or odd*? Or is this utopia?

I know that I can give these rows a class and make it work, but that is not what I am aiming for. Would love to solve it with CSS3, even if `IE` won't support it. Is there a way to do this?

HTML:

```
<table class="dummyclass">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="This_should_get_a_background_color">
                    <th>Dummytext</th>
                    <td><a href="#">Dummy dummy</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="This_should_get_a_background_color">
                  <th>Dumminho</th>
                  <td>Golazo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="This_should_get_a_background_color">
                  <th>Great game</th>
                  <td>yesterday</td>
            </tr>

             <tr class="no-background-please">
                  <th>Dummytext</th>
                  <td><a href="#">Dummy dummy</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="no-background-please">
                 <th>Dumminho</th>
                 <td>Golazo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="no-background-please">
                 <th>Great game</th>
                 <td>yesterday</td>
               </tr>

             <tr class="This_should_get_a_background_color">
                 <th>Dummytext</th>
                 <td><a href="#">Dummy dummy</a></td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="This_should_get_a_background_color">
                    <th>Dumminho</th>
                    <td>Golazo</td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="This_should_get_a_background_color">
                    <th>Great game</th>
                    <td>yesterday</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
```

And for the `CSS`, well I tried a lot of things like `tr:nth-of-type(2n+1)`, but I saw here that that is not an option for me: **http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/**

**For a fiddle, check here: *http://jsfiddle.net/95vrb/1/***

I have given the rows descriptive classnames, so that you can understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a better way of doing it but this works. 
Basically it will add the background to every 6th child, starting from the 1st, 2nd and 3rd element.

http://jsfiddle.net/95vrb/2/

```
tr:nth-child(6n + 3), 
tr:nth-child(6n + 2), 
tr:nth-child(6n + 1) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

I find this to be an excellent introduction to `:nth-child` http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
.dummyclass tr:nth-of-type(-n+3), //First three rows
.dummyclass tr:nth-of-type(n+7) { //Last three rows
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shiazure/95vrb/5/

Of course, this is tailored to the example you gave, and would need to be changed based on the number of cells/rows.

Comment: That doesn't get the last three rows. Only the first three